# AWS tech stack solution for a static website

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a project where I am building a simple single page app, that needs to pull data from an api only once a day. I have a backend that I am thinking of building with `golang`, where I need to do 2 things:

1) Have a scheduled job that would once a day update the `DB` with the new data.

2) Serve that data to the frontend. Since the data would only be updated once a day, I would like to `cache` it after each update.

Since, the number of options that AWS is offering is a bit overwhelming, I am wondering what would be the ideal solution for this scenario. Should I use `lambda` that connects to `DB` and updates it with a scheduled job? Should I create then a separate REST API lambda where I would pull that data from the `DB` and call it from the frontend?
I would really appreciate suggestions for this problem.

Comment: Deploy the single page app from an S3 bucket. In the S3 bucket have a file called data.json and contains the data you want to display, and each day a lambda updates that file with the new info in the database. You wouldn't even need an API. Some limitations would be if the data grew too large (over 512MB) the lambda wouldn't be able to store it in the /tmp folder and upload it to the bucket, but thats a huge file of JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Her is my suggestion;

- Create a lambda function

  - it will fetch required information from database
  - You may use S3 or DynamoDB to save your content. Both of the solutions may be free please check for [free tier offers](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) depending on your usage
  - it will save the fetched content to S3 or DynamoDB (you may check Dax for DynamoDB caching)
- Create an Api gateway and integrate it to your lambda (Elastic LoadBalancer is another choice)
- Create a `Schedule Expressions` on CloudWatch to trigger lambda daily
- Make a request from your front end to Api Gateway or ELB.
- You may use Route 53 for domain naming.

Your lambda should have two separate functions, one is to respond schedule expression, the other one is to serve your content via communicating with S3/DynamoDB.

Edit:

Here is the architecture

[image]

Edit:

If the content is going to be static, you may configure a S3 bucket for static site serving and your daily lambda may write it in there when it is triggered. Then you no longer need api gateway and DynamoDB.

here is the documentation for [s3 static content](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great suggestion!

Comment: @Leff i added another comment for %100 static content, please check it.